# Access Crash logs data on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, logging

I'm looking for the way to get crash logs data on the iPhone OS.

I found getting the logs this way:

1) Sync your iPhone

2) Browse to the following folders. Note that DEVICE_NAME will be the name if your iPhone as shown in iTunes.

Mac OS X : /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice//

Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\Application Data\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter\

Windows Vista: C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\

3) Each log file will begin with the name of the application. Create a zip file from these applications (Mac: Right-click->Compress, Windows Right-Click->WinZip) and then email it to the developer

BUT!!! I don't wanna get this way.

I want something like a button embedded in my app where the users can send me the crash logs whenever they have a problem. Is it possible to do this? Please let me know. thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can’t access the logs themselves, but you *can* catch uncaught exceptions and generate your own crash logs. Check out [this link](http://www.restoroot.com/Blog/2008/10/18/crash-reporter-for-iphone-applications/) for more information.